# Trouble returning value in custom Spring Validator

Tags: java, spring, validation, date, spring-boot

Given the try/catch block below, how can I return the `return !dateToDate.before(dateFromDate) && dateFromDate.before(dateToDate);` value in the actual method scope? It wants me to return false. I can't include the proper return value where I want it, i.e. where `return false` is currently located.

```
public class YourDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidDates,
        TypeToBeValidated> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidDates constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TypeToBeValidated value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String dateTo = value.getDateTo();
        String dateFrom = value.getDateFrom();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormat);
        Date dateToDate = null;
        Date dateFromDate = null;
        try {
            dateFromDate = formatter.parse(dateFrom);
            dateToDate = formatter.parse(dateTo);
            return !dateToDate.before(dateFromDate) && dateFromDate.before(dateToDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

**Desired Code:**

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(TypeToBeValidated value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String dateTo = value.getDateTo();
        String dateFrom = value.getDateFrom();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormat);
        Date dateFromDate = formatter.parse(dateFrom);
        Date dateToDate = formatter.parse(dateTo);
        return !dateToDate.before(dateFromDate) && dateFromDate.before(dateToDate);
    }
```

I can't throw the ParseException in the @Overriden `isValid` class. But I can't put the return value in the try/catch block for formatter. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to catch the checked exception, your desired implementation is not possible. If your goal is to have only single return point form the method then you can use a result variable which you assign in the try/catch block:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(TypeToBeValidated value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    String dateTo = value.getDateTo();
    String dateFrom = value.getDateFrom();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormat);
    Date dateToDate = null;
    Date dateFromDate = null;
    boolean valid = false;
    try {
        dateFromDate = formatter.parse(dateFrom);
        dateToDate = formatter.parse(dateTo);
        valid = !dateToDate.before(dateFromDate) && dateFromDate.before(dateToDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to handle the exception outside the method, you can rethrow it as a unchecked exception:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(TypeToBeValidated value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    String dateTo = value.getDateTo();
    String dateFrom = value.getDateFrom();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormat);
    Date dateToDate = null;
    Date dateFromDate = null;
    try {
        dateFromDate = formatter.parse(dateFrom);
        dateToDate = formatter.parse(dateTo);
        return !dateToDate.before(dateFromDate) && dateFromDate.before(dateToDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you always use something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(TypeToBeValidated value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    String dateTo = value.getDateTo();
    String dateFrom = value.getDateFrom();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtil.dateFormat);
    boolean isValid = false;
    try {
        Date dateFromDate = formatter.parse(dateFrom);
        Date dateToDate = formatter.parse(dateTo);
        isValid = dateFromDate.before(dateToDate);
        if( isValid ) {
            return true;
        }

        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
                String.format("Error: dateFromDate (%s) is not before dateToDate (%s)!", 
                    dateFromDate.toString(), 
                    dateToDate.toString()
                )
            )
            .addConstraintViolation();
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
                String.format("Exception while validating dateFromDate (%s), dateToDate (%s)! Reason: %s", 
                    dateFromDate.toString(), 
                    dateToDate.toString(), 
                    e.getMessage()
                )
            )
            .addConstraintViolation();
    }

    return false;
}
```

In this case you'll always know, why and with what data your vaildation failed.